# Handle concurrency in SQL Server stored procedure with timestamp

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, concurrency, sapb1

I'm trying to apply concurrency to prevent 2 users updates the same table.

Unfortunately need to return 0 if concurrency happens, then need to block the second user update the table.

If no concurrency happens, then need to return 1 as I'm using SAP b1 forms as the front end to fire the stored procedure.

But below stored procedure won't work as both the request get executed and updates 2 time.

Please advise me to prevent and correct this issue.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateDocumentSEQ]
    @ID INT 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @TransactionName VARCHAR(20)= 'Demotran1';
 
    DECLARE @rowcount int = -1 

    BEGIN TRAN @TransactionName
      BEGIN TRY
          UPDATE [ADDON_SC_DOCUMENT_SEQ1] 
          SET [Index] = [Index] + 1
          WHERE ID = @ID
            AND [DOCUMENT_NAME] = 'SHIPMENT_CONFIRMATION' 
            AND [SEQUENCE] = 'Primary' 
            AND [TimeStamp] = (SELECT [TimeStamp] 
                               FROM [ADDON_SC_DOCUMENT_SEQ1]  
                               WHERE ID = @ID)  

          SELECT @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT

          IF (@rowcount = 0) -- No row updated => Concurrency Error
          BEGIN
              SELECT '0' AS [COUNTX]
          END
          ELSE
          BEGIN
              COMMIT TRAN @TransactionName
 
              SELECT '1' AS [COUNTX]
          END    
       END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION @TransactionName
    END CATCH   
END
```

Frontend code:

```
private void UpdateDocNumber3()
{
    try
    {
        SAPbobsCOM.Company _Company = SAPCompany.GetDICompany();
        Recordset oRecSet3 = (Recordset)_Company.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset);

        string sqlQuery = string.Empty;
        object _Timestamp = null;
        sqlQuery = "EXEC UpdateDocumentSEQ 1";

        //dt6.Clear();
        dt6.ExecuteQuery(sqlQuery);

        if (dt6.GetValue("COUNTX", 0).ToString() == "0")
        {
            SAPbouiCOM.Framework.Application.SBO_Application.StatusBar.SetSystemMessage("RecordData was changed by someone else, please refresh and try again 1 ", SAPbouiCOM.BoMessageTime.bmt_Short, SAPbouiCOM.BoStatusBarMessageType.smt_Success);
        }
        else
        {
            SAPbouiCOM.Framework.Application.SBO_Application.StatusBar.SetSystemMessage("OK 3 ", SAPbouiCOM.BoMessageTime.bmt_Short, SAPbouiCOM.BoStatusBarMessageType.smt_Success);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        SAPbouiCOM.Framework.Application.SBO_Application.StatusBar.SetSystemMessage(e.ToString(), BoMessageTime.bmt_Short, BoStatusBarMessageType.smt_Error, "", "", "", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "concurrency", you appear to have some filter on `Timestamp` but the logic is unclear. You are missing a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` in the first half of the `IF`

Comment: @Charlieface here concurrency refers to multiple users trying to update the same table same time, need to prevent it. For 2 users having different TimeStamp values first user will have the chance to update, hence the for second user will not be able to update so record count will be zero, this is how I block it

Comment: @Charlieface even if i add ROLLBACK to first if in Tsql still update happens , how to block this based on TimeStamp ?

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to pass in the user's current `Timestamp` value as a parameter and compare it. So instead of `AND [TimeStamp] = (SELECT [TimeStamp] FROM [ADDON_SC_DOCUMENT_SEQ1] WHERE ID = @ID)` you need `AND [TimeStamp] = @TimeStamp`

Comment: *update the same table same time* - the same **table**? It's a typo, right?

Comment: Your TSQL error handling is wrong as well. In your catch block you eat the error. The caller has no idea that an error occurred nor what that error was. And why do you need a transaction for a single update statement? Don't over-complicate things. Lastly `SELECT '1' AS [COUNTX]` that is not how procedure communicate success/failure to a caller. The caller will catch errors in the form of an exception. There shouldn't be a resultset to retrieve and then interpret.

Comment: What is the data type of the `TimeStamp` column? In addition to passing in the user's current `TimeStamp` value as Charlieface suggests, if it's not the built-in [`rowversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) data type then you're also going to have to manually handle incrementing it to a new value in the `update` statement.

Answer (score 2):

The proc should simply look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateDocumentSEQ] @ID INT, @TIMESTAMP rowversion
AS
BEGIN 
    UPDATE [ADDON_SC_DOCUMENT_SEQ1] 
    SET [Index] = [Index] + 1
    WHERE ID = @ID
    AND [DOCUMENT_NAME] = 'SHIPMENT_CONFIRMATION' 
    AND [SEQUENCE] = 'Primary' 
    AND [TimeStamp] = @TIMESTAMP

    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT [COUNTX]
END
```

There's no need for a transaction when you have only one DML statement.